# The Pico unity openxr sdk is incompatible with openxr 1.9.1, but I can't downgrade the openxr version in the editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, openxr

I am a student, developing a VR game in unity for the meta quest 3 and PICO 4. As they are both compatible with openxr, I assumed it was possible to have the same project run on both headsets. I can build just fine for the quest 3, but when building for the PICO 4, I am unable to play the game. After changing the settings to allow for PICO 4 controller support, I get the following error: "only unity openXR plugin prior to version 1.9.1 is supported right now". This is repeated on the "known issues" page of the SDK, which states that version 1.9.1 is not supported due to a memory leak.

Unfortunately I cannot change the openxr version used in the project. It seems the way it works with unity, is that the engine automatically installs version 1.9.1, with no way for the user to change it. I can push a "fix" button that states that it changes the version back to an earlier one, but it seems that this older version is immediately updated back to 1.9.1. So I am stuck, and hope that someone here smarter or more experienced than me can help.

This is only an issue when building for the headset. When testing in the editor, it works decently with both headsets, even when I don't enable PICO controller support.